# Export as SVG in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, svg

I have opened a PNG image in Photoshop. I want to export as SVG and make the image pixelated. How do I do this?

When I zoom in the image in Photoshop, the image is pixelated. I want to have the exact same effect but in an SVG export.

Comment: Yes you can use Export assets in Photoshop cc

Comment: Photoshop CS4 cannot "Save as" SVG. I ended up using the online converter [aconvert](https://www.aconvert.com/image/psd-to-svg/). Use Inkscape afterwards to edit the SVG.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot export SVG with Adobe Photoshop. The only way to achieve what you want is to copy the image to Adobe Illustrator and save it as an SVG file.

I'm not sure why you would do that, though, since the point of SVG is to make **[Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)** so you can resize the image without it getting pixelated. By exporting it as SVG you basically wrap the PNG code you already have in XML - you might just as easily use a PNG file instead.

Comment: Photoshop’s Export As and Generator can both create SVGs. They include shape layers as vector paths, so the results can be 100% vector, depending on the document.

Answer (score 3):

depending how complex the "image" is you could run a trace in illustration and then export it to svg from there

**Instructions:**

1. Open AI
2. new doc
3. place image on artboard
4. on the toolbar you will get an option to "trace" there is also a dropdown next to it for more options on what type of trace
5. ungroup seleciton if you need to edit

enjoy your vector trace

Comment: Hey Sergio. Can you edit your answer to include some instructions?

Comment: instructions added. just need to export to svg after you have your trace

Comment: No Problem, were you able to do what you needed?

Comment: > "Open AI" - The question asks how to do it with Photoshop, not Adobe Illustrator.